# In semantic segmentation using Fully convolutional networks, why is Cross Entropy loss preferred over L1 or L2 losses?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, deep-learning

I am training a fully convolutional network with Encoder-Decoder architecture for the task of Image Segmentation and currently am using the Binary Cross Entropy loss for foreground/background prediction.

I was trying to search and read about why Cross entropy loss is used instead of L1 or L2 losses. Cross entropy loss fails to capture the overall layout of the image, whereas L1 and L2 take the overall image reconstruction into account.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, semantic segmentation task is a dense classification task, which means you need to classify every single pixel to certain classes. Usually, using cross entropy loss will perform better than l1 or l2 loss in classification tasks. L1 or L2 loss would be more suitable for regression problems. This article well explained the difference between them. [Picking Loss Functions - A comparison between MSE, Cross Entropy, and Hinge Loss](https://rohanvarma.me/Loss-Functions/)

There is another kind of loss function for semantic segmentation, which is dice loss as well as its variants. As far as I know, dice based loss dominates in medical imaging segmentation field.